# Access HTML input array field via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, input

The following HTML code references javascript to update another input field in the same row based on calculated values. I can't seem to reference the HTML field as it is coming back undefined. The issue is that the HTML input array value is NAME[EmployeeID] so I'm passing the EmployeeID to the function in order to reference the correct HTML field. Just can't seem to figure out how to format the innerHTML command.

```
<script language="javascript"><!--
function updateAdvance(eWorked, eID, AdvanceAmt, eRate) {
  if (AdvanceAmt > 0) {
    var ePay    = eWorked * eRate;

    if (ePay < AdvanceAmt) {
      document.getElementById(Amt2Adv[eID]).innerHTML = AdvanceAmt.toFixed(2);
    } else {
      document.getElementById(Amt2Adv[eID]).innerHTML = ePay.toFixed(2);
    }
  }
}
//--></script>
```

HTML Code

```
              <tr>
                <td colspan="10"><form name="compensation" action="https://somewhere.com/something.php?date=2018-11-09&action=compensation" method="post"><table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
                  <tr>
                    <td class="contentHeading" align="center" colspan="8"><b>Compensation</b></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center"><b>Select</b></td>
                    <td align="center"><b>Employee</b></td>
                    <td align="center"><b>Type</b></td>
                    <td align="center"><b>Period</b></td>
                    <td align="center"><b>Amount</b></td>
                    <td align="center"><b>Worked</b></td>
                    <td align="center"><b>Amt->Adv</b></td>
                    <td align="center"><b>Advance</b></td>
                    <td align="center"><b>GiftCard</b></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="employee[4]" value="1" CHECKED></td>
                    <td align="center">Joe Fabitz</td>
                    <td align="center">Cash</td>
                    <td align="center">Hourly</td>
                    <td align="center">$10.00</td>
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="worked[4]" value="8.00" size="3" onKeyUp="updateAdvance(this.value, '4','30.00','10.00')"><input type="hidden" name="period[4]" value="1"></td>
                    <td align="center">$<input type="text" name="amt2adv[4]" value="0.00" size="4"></td>
                    <td align="center">$<input type="text" name="advance[4]" value="0.00" size="4"></td>
                    <td align="center">0</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="employee[3]" value="1" CHECKED></td>
                    <td align="center">Jane Fabitz</td>
                    <td align="center">Cash</td>
                    <td align="center">Hourly</td>
                    <td align="center">$10.00</td>
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="worked[3]" value="8.00" size="3" onKeyUp="updateAdvance(this.value, '3','100.00','10.00')"><input type="hidden" name="period[3]" value="1"></td>
                    <td align="center">$<input type="text" name="amt2adv[3]" value="20.00" size="4"></td>
                    <td align="center">$<input type="text" name="advance[3]" value="0.00" size="4"></td>
                    <td align="center">0</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center" colspan="8"><button type="submit" name="" class="css3button">Save</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="https://somewhere.com/something.php?date=2018-11-09"><button type="button" name="" class="css3button">Cancel</button></a></td>
                  </tr>
                </table></form></td>
              </tr>
```

Comment: You don't appear to have any `id`s at all in your HTML, so what is `getElementById` supposed to select? Also, what are all the parameters in your function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select an element with `getElementById`, you will need an element that has an `id` attribute as mentioned by [CertainPerformance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53255639/access-html-input-array-field-via-javascript#comment93395867_53255639) in the comment.

If you wish to get the elements by their name, you can use

- `document.querySelector` which returns the first element that matches the provided `query`, or
- `document.getElementsByName` which returns all the elements with the supplied `name`

To set the display value of `input`s, you will need to set the `value` of your `input`, not `innerHTML`.

Also, `String` does not have `toFixed` method, you will need to parse `AdvanceAmt` to `Number` first.

```js
function updateAdvance(eWorked, eID, AdvanceAmt, eRate) {  
  AdvanceAmt = parseFloat(AdvanceAmt);
  
  if (AdvanceAmt > 0) {
    var ePay = eWorked * eRate;
    var selector = `input[name="amt2adv\[${eID}\]"]`;

    if (ePay < AdvanceAmt) {
      document.querySelector(selector).value = AdvanceAmt.toFixed(2);
    } else {
      document.querySelector(selector).value = ePay.toFixed(2);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="10"><form name="compensation" action="https://somewhere.com/something.php?date=2018-11-09&action=compensation" method="post"><table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
      <tr>
        <td class="contentHeading" align="center" colspan="8"><b>Compensation</b></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center"><b>Select</b></td>
        <td align="center"><b>Employee</b></td>
        <td align="center"><b>Type</b></td>
        <td align="center"><b>Period</b></td>
        <td align="center"><b>Amount</b></td>
        <td align="center"><b>Worked</b></td>
        <td align="center"><b>Amt->Adv</b></td>
        <td align="center"><b>Advance</b></td>
        <td align="center"><b>GiftCard</b></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="employee[4]" value="1" CHECKED></td>
        <td align="center">Joe Fabitz</td>
        <td align="center">Cash</td>
        <td align="center">Hourly</td>
        <td align="center">$10.00</td>
        <td align="center"><input type="text" name="worked[4]" value="8.00" size="3" onKeyUp="updateAdvance(this.value, '4','30.00','10.00')"><input type="hidden" name="period[4]" value="1"></td>
        <td align="center">$<input type="text" name="amt2adv[4]" value="0.00" size="4"></td>
        <td align="center">$<input type="text" name="advance[4]" value="0.00" size="4"></td>
        <td align="center">0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="employee[3]" value="1" CHECKED></td>
        <td align="center">Jane Fabitz</td>
        <td align="center">Cash</td>
        <td align="center">Hourly</td>
        <td align="center">$10.00</td>
        <td align="center"><input type="text" name="worked[3]" value="8.00" size="3" onKeyUp="updateAdvance(this.value, '3','100.00','10.00')"><input type="hidden" name="period[3]" value="1"></td>
        <td align="center">$<input type="text" name="amt2adv[3]" value="20.00" size="4"></td>
        <td align="center">$<input type="text" name="advance[3]" value="0.00" size="4"></td>
        <td align="center">0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="8"><button type="submit" name="" class="css3button">Save</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="https://somewhere.com/something.php?date=2018-11-09"><button type="button" name="" class="css3button">Cancel</button></a></td>
      </tr>
    </table></form></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```